# make fontFamily cssproperty single quoted

Tags: javascript, string

```js
/*
**
* Change styling based on given parameters
**
**/
function changeStylingOnChange(objects){ 
 let element = objects,
  input = element.input,
  changeSelector = element.changeSelector,
  cssProperty = element.cssProperty,
  pixels = element.pixels;
    
  if(cssProperty === 'fontFamily'){
   changeFontFamily(input, changeSelector, cssProperty);
  } else {
   pixels ? 
    document.querySelector(changeSelector).style[cssProperty] = `${input.value}px` : 
    document.querySelector(changeSelector).style[cssProperty] = `${input.value}`;
  }
}

function changeFontFamily(input, changeSelector, cssProperty) {
 var fontFamily = input.value.replace("+", " ");
 var link = document.getElementById('fontLink');

 if(link) {
  link.href = `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=${input.value}`;
 } else {
  var link = document.createElement('link');
  link.id = 'fontLink';
  link.rel = 'stylesheet';
  link.href = `https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=${input.value}`;
  document.head.appendChild(link);
 }

 document.querySelector(changeSelector).style[cssProperty] = fontFamily;
}
```

```html
<select class="exitIntentFontFamily" name="fontFamily" onchange="changeStylingOnChange({input:this, changeSelector:'.exit-intent-wrapper', cssProperty:'fontFamily', pixels:false})">
                            <option value="ABeeZee">ABeeZee</option>
                            <option value="Abel">Abel</option>
                            <option value="Abhaya+Libre">Abhaya Libre</option>
                            <option value="Abril+Fatface">Abril Fatface</option></select>
                            
<div class="exit-intent-wrapper">
            <span class="close-btn" onclick="closeExitIntent()"></span>
            <div class="exit-intent-content-wrapper">
                <div class="exit-intent-header-wrapper">
                    <h1 class="column exit-intent-header">Test</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="exit-intent-inner" style="font-size: 24px;">
                    <p class="column description">Register now to be the first to get all the updates</p>
                    <div class="exit-intent-body">
                        <div class="column">
                            <form action="" class="form">
                                <div class="inner-form">
                                    <div class="fs_row">
                                        <div class="column">
                                            <input type="text" placeholder="email" class="email-input">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>


                                <div class="fs_row">
                                    <div class="column">
                                        <button class="fs_button"></button>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I assigning a font-family to an element but want to assign this font family single quoted.

this is the piece of javascript where I append the `font-family` as css property

```
var fontFamily = input.value.replace("+", " ");
document.querySelector(changeSelector).style[cssProperty] = fontFamily;
```

Is rendered like this:

```
<div class="exit-intent-wrapper left" style="background: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: "Allerta Stencil";">
```

How can I assign this variable `fontFamily` single qouted?

Comment: why does it matter how it is rendered? It is just how the browser is displaying it, it should not be an issue.

Comment: Not sure why it really matters, but if your really bothered.  One option is to just set the whole style. -> `document.querySelector("div").setAttribute("style", "background: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-family: 'Allerta Stencil';")`

Comment: @epascarello it is an issue because people are going to copy this code into tag manager and there it throws an error because that styling attribute is getting cut of

Comment: Can you add a [mcve] showing how the strings don't get escaped?

Comment: @Luca here you go

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use quotes I guess, Without quotes it's work fine but I haven't tested for font families which has white space.

Below snippet shows dynamic font adding to element

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var font = document.getElementById('font').value;
  document.getElementById('content').style['font-family'] = font;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="font" value="Ubuntu">
<button id="btn"> CHANGE FONT </button>
<p id="content">
Hello
</p>
```

Comment: I know but because of the white space it is wrapped in double quotes

Comment: I did tested your code but this is still double quoted when there is a space in between

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I try setting styles like this JS will just escape the double qoutes and include them like this:

```
style="font-family: \"Allerta Stencil\";"
```

```js
let div = document.querySelector("#test");

div.style.fontFamily = "Allerta Stencil";

console.log(div)
```

```html
<div id="test">Foo</div>
```

Comment: How do I escape that fontFamily variable?

Comment: You don't need to escape it, you just take the string from wherever you get it and pass it to the div's style.fontFamily property and it get's escaped automagically

Comment: for me this is not working still double quoted without that escape